# AngularJS parsing CSS code

Tags: json, angularjs, parsing

[image]I'm using angularjs with wordpress API and on scope output I have problem to parse the returned CSS.

For HTML parsing I've been using

```
<div ng-repeat ="article in post">
    <div ng-bind-html="article.content">
        {{ article.content }}
    </div>
</div>

angular.module('blancAppApp')
  .controller('SlugCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

    $http.get('/wp-json/posts/?type=post&type=page&filter[name]=' + $routeParams.slug ).success(function(res){  
        $scope.post = res;
      return $scope.post;
      console.log($scope.post);
    });
});
```

this one works fine but on CSS I have the following raw output

```
#gallery-1 { margin: auto; } #gallery-1 .gallery-item { float: left; margin-top: 10px; text-align: center; width: 50%; } #gallery-1 img { border: 2px solid #cfcfcf; } #gallery-1 .gallery-caption { margin-left: 0; }
```

JSON

```
\n<style type='text\/css'>\n#gallery-1 {\nmargin: auto;\n}\n#gallery-1 .gallery-item {\nfloat: left;\nmargin-top: 10px;\ntext-align: center;\nwidth: 50%;\n}\n#gallery-1 img {\nborder: 2px solid #cfcfcf;\n}\n#gallery-1 .gallery-caption {\nmargin-left: 0;\n}\n<\/style>\n
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Elaborate, show an example.

Comment: that looks like valid CSS to me. I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve, what your code is, what you expect it to do and what it does instead.

Comment: yes is a valid CSS but on the screen projected

Comment: I asked you twice to explain what you were trying to do, what your code was and what your expected it to do. The only thing we know now is that some unknown code, supposed to do an unknown thing, displays CSS in the page. How could we help?

Comment: I think I've been explaining my problem I try to output some json which contains CSS so what is not clear I've been adding my controller is it good like or I get couple of more downvotes?

Comment: I think there's a problem with the escaping and newlines in your string.

Comment: Oh yes I will make a filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Wrapping your css in a style tag.

Remove the escaping of /, you don't need that (both start and end  tags.)

also try to remove the newlines (\n)

Comment: how does the surrounding output look like, please post the surrounding dom, and how does the response look like in the network inspector (f12)

Comment: I've been posting the JSON on this part